# Unable to calculate the total values in table columns

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am binding data through a for loop here I'm facing issues related to the while calculating the total in one column

I have a location which are bound through dropdown say

```
id  location
--  ---------
0    All
1    A
2    B
3    C
4    D
```

by selecting a table im getting that particular table data based on location wise when i press **all** i will get all location values here below im getting the values location wise in the table while im totaling the values it is taking all the location values instead of choosen location

```
A location    B Location  C Location   D Location
----------    ----------  ----------   ----------
10            20          30           40
```

when I select Location A it should display total as 10 but instead it is displaying 90 as total 
below is my loop

```
this.serv.ByReportId(this.table).subscribe(result=>{
      debugger;
      console.log(this.table.ReportId)
      console.log(result)
      if(result!=null)
        this.resultData=result.Table;
      for(var i=0;i<this.resultData.length;i++){

        this.NetAmts=this.NetAmts+parseFloat(this.resultData[i].NetAmt);

      }

    },error=>{console.log(error)})
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you create a plunker or stackblitz for the same

Comment: you have not given us enough code to understand...

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well you want to sum A, B, C, D locations:

With `for loop`:

```js
const array = ['10', '20', '30', '40'];
let sum = 0;

for(let i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
 sum += parseFloat(array[i]);
}

console.log(sum); // 100
```

With [Array#Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b):

```js
// Insted Number you can also use parseFloat or parseInt
const array = ['10', '20', '30', '40'];
let sum = array.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + Number(cur), 0);
console.log(sum);
```